# Is it true that $\boldsymbol v= \boldsymbol w \times \boldsymbol r \implies \boldsymbol w = \frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol v$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was asked to prove that $$\boldsymbol v= \boldsymbol w \times \boldsymbol r \implies \boldsymbol w = \frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol v$$ (Where $\boldsymbol r  = x \boldsymbol i + y \boldsymbol j + z \boldsymbol k$ is the usual displacement). But I don't believe it's quite accurate.
My attempt:
$$\begin{align}\frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol v&=\frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla \times \boldsymbol (\boldsymbol w \times \boldsymbol r)\\&= \frac 12[\boldsymbol w (\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol r) -\boldsymbol r(\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol w )+(\boldsymbol r \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\boldsymbol w -\boldsymbol w (\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol r)]\\&=\frac 12[3\boldsymbol w -\boldsymbol r(\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol w )+(\boldsymbol r \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\boldsymbol w -\boldsymbol w ]\\&=\frac 12\left[2\boldsymbol w -\boldsymbol r\left(\dfrac{\partial w_i }{\partial x_i}\right)+ r_i\left(\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol w }{\partial x_i}\right)\right]\end{align}$$
When I write an index $i$ it means one is to take the sum for all possible $i$. (In this case, 3 dimensions). And those last two terms don't seem to cancel out if $\boldsymbol w$ is a vector field whose $\boldsymbol j$ components depend on $x$, for example.

Comment: Heuristically, using $\nabla \sim \frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}}$, what you're asking for is the equivalent formula in 1D $$v = wr \implies w \sim \frac{d}{dr}v$$ which only had a chance of being true if $w$ were a constant. The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from curl shenangians as this is simply a heuristic after all.

Comment: When you do a calculation like this, it's helpful to work with the $j$th component, thus making expressions such as $-r_j\frac{\partial w_i}{\partial x_i}+r_i\frac{\partial w_j}{\partial x_i}$ easier to work with. However, in this case I think it's simply a matter of "we assumed $\vec{w}$ (surprisingly not $\vec{\omega}$) is $\vec{x}$-independent", as @NinadMunshi suggested.

Comment: you are right. However, if this is a homework problem, most likely from a vector calculus class, then it's also customary to have that $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector, $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a generic vector valued function $\boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{r})$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$ is a constant, most often standing for angular momentum. 

Conventions like these are usually mentioned once at the beginning of the class and followed throughout.

Comment: It's from a list of exercises, but it was never assumed that $\boldsymbol w$ is a constant, at least in the classes I went to. Now I see that probably the exercise was taken from somewhere else without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the formula holds only for constant angular velocity $\boldsymbol{w}\,.$ The calculations then become very straightforward:
$$
\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{w}\times\boldsymbol{r}=\left(\matrix{w_1\\w_2\\w_3}\right)\times\left(\matrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}\right)=\left(\matrix{w_2x_3-w_3x_2\\w_3x_1-w_1x_3\\w_1x_2-w_2x_1}\right)
$$
$$
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{v}=\left(\matrix{\partial_1\\\partial_2\\\partial_3}\right)\times\left(\matrix{w_2x_3-w_3x_2\\w_3x_1-w_1x_3\\w_1x_2-w_2x_1}\right)=\left(\matrix{w_1+w_1\\w_2+w_2\\w_3+w_3}\right)=2\boldsymbol{w}\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

In index notation:

$$ v  = \omega \times r \implies v^j = \epsilon^{jmn} \omega_m r_n$$

Taking curl (assuming constant $\omega)$ would be equivalent to:

$$ (\nabla \times v)_k  = (\epsilon_{ijk} \nabla^i v^j ) = \big( \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon^{jmn}   \nabla^i(\omega_m r_n)\big)  = \big(\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon^{jmn}   \omega_m \nabla^i r_n  \big) = - ( \delta_{jik}^{jmn} \omega_m \nabla^i r_n)= -( \delta_{ik}^{mn} \omega_m \nabla^i r_n)$$

Now clearly in Cartesian coordinates $\nabla^i r_n = \delta_n^i$, we have:

$$ (\nabla \times v)_k =- (\delta_{nk}^{mn} \omega_m)= \delta_{nk}^{nm} \omega_m = 2 \omega_k$$

In Vector Calculus notation:

$$ \nabla \times v  = 2 \omega$$